# problem with favorite button in list view Flutter/Dart

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

guys i have this code down here and problem is when i click on my favorite icon, all of icons in list is going to be true!!
here is the code:

```
static const likedKey = 'liked_key';

  bool liked;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _restorePersistedPreference();
  }

  void _restorePersistedPreference() async {
    var preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var liked = preferences.getBool(likedKey) ?? false;
    setState(() => this.liked = liked);
  }

  void _persistPreference() async {
    setState(() => liked = !liked);
    var preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    preferences.setBool(likedKey, liked);
  }
```

And my favorite button:

```
IconButton(
                icon: Icon(
                  liked ? Icons.favorite : Icons.favorite_border,
                  color: liked ? Colors.red : Colors.grey,
                ),
                onPressed: _persistPreference,
              ),
```

Comment: Can you provide the code of your list with all icons?

Comment: my list is connected to api and if you want, i will put my code

Comment: You could use a list to store liked flag for each button. But a better approach will be creating a custom widget, which has inbuilt logic for liked .

Comment: can you provide example on my code?

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because all of your Favourites buttons depend on one **liked** variable state so as soon as the state of liked variable changes it affects all favorites button. You should use SQLite to store the state of each button (Recommended) or a separate key for each button (Not recommended).

Comment: So what do you recommend?

Comment: SQLite for small programs is not suitable. I recommend Hive